# Showing f(0) is bound above by geometric mean of supremum over intervals?

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-inequality

So I am working on the following problem.

> Suppose that $f$ is entire and $n$ is a fixed positive integer. If
>   $$I_k:=\left[\frac{2(k-1)\pi}{n},\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right],$$
>   for $k=1,2,\dots,n$ and $$\alpha_k:=\sup_{\theta\in I_k}|f(e^{i\theta})|,$$ prove that $|f(0)|\leq (\alpha_1\alpha_2\cdots\alpha_n)^\frac{1}{n}.$

I began by noting that $m(I_k)=\frac{2\pi}{n}\forall k.$ Then I used the Mean Value Property to get
$$|f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{I_k} |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2\pi \alpha_k}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\alpha_k}{n}.$$

Now I can see that what I have on the RHS is the arithmetic mean, but in general $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\right)^\frac{1}{n}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\alpha_i}{n}.$$ That seems to suggest that my route is not producing the *sharpest* bound.

Next, I though maybe I could use Jensen's to try and force the geometric mean to appear, but I haven't produced anything useful as of yet.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The expected (easier) way to prove it is probably [the method used here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487675/let-m-1-m-2-m-3-m-4-be-the-suprema-of-f-on-the-edges-of-a-square-show-tha).

Comment: In my class we didn't cover Schwarz-Christoffel formula, but I am working through a prelim packet and the curriculum changes over time. Thanks for the link. I will have to read up on that as well.

Comment: I meant the method from the answer. No such thing as Schwarz-Christoffel is needed. Just the plain old maximum modulus principle and the right idea.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I just woke up and am still a bit groggy. I'll try and work the problem that way as well. Can never have too many solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(0)=0$ there is nothing to prove. From now on assume $f(0)\ne0$.

Let $a_1,\dots,a_m$ be the zeroes of $f$ in $\{|z|<1\}$. Suppose first that $f(z)\ne0$ if $|z|=1$. By Jensen's formula
$$
\log|f(0)|=\sum_{i=1}^m\log|a_k|+\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|f(e^{i\theta})|\,d\theta\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log|\alpha_k|,
$$
which gives the desired inequality.

If $f(z)=0$ for some $z$ with $|z|=1$, take a sequence $r_n\to1$ such that $f$ does not vanish on $\{|z|=r_n\}$, apply the above argument on the disk of radius $r_n$ and let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use something other than "$a$" which is so alike to "$α$"?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't believer we covered this formula in my class (by Jensen's I meant the inequality involving convex functions), but I just read through the statement of the theorem (and proof) and your solution looks good. I appreciate it.